# What is the mistake in the following contradiction to the solution of the Monty Hall problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, monty-hall

Let us say in a game show there are three doors - 1,2 and 3 - behind which are hidden 1 special prize and 2 useless objects. The host knows which door leads to which object. Let there be two contestants in the game - $A$ and $B$. First, $A$ is asked to play the game. $A$ chooses Door 1. Then the host opens Door 3 revealing that it is not the Door leading to the prize. He then asks if $A$ wants to switch. It is widely known that switching to Door 2 would give you twice the chance of winning, so he switches. Then, $B$, who doesn't know anything about $A$'s game is asked to come and play. He chooses Door 2. Then the host opens Door 3 again and asks $B$ if he wants to switch. $B$ says yes, because it gives him twice the chance of winning. So, for $A$, it is more likely that the prize is behind Door 2 and for $B$, it is more likely that the prize is behind Door 1. How can this happen if there is nothing unique about $A$ or $B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at it this way - suppose the host has decided he likes door #3, so he'll open it if at all possible. Two contestants play, blind to each other, and choose door #1 and door #2 respectively. There are three possibilities:

- If the prize is behind door #1, the host will open door #3 for both. Both players switch, one of them wins.
- If the prize is behind door #2, the host will open door #3 for both. Both players switch, one of them wins.
- If the prize is behind door #3, the host can't open his favorite door, door #3, so he'll open door #2 for the first player and door #1 for the second. Both players switch to door #3, and both players win.

By saying that the host opened door #3 for both, we rule out that last case, introducing new information not known to either player.

Comment: Very good answer!

Comment: Re: the edit - I probably would have caught it myself, but I had just hit post when the airport shuttle arrived. Now? I'm at the gate with a few hours to kill.

Comment: Nice answer @jmerry . I realize that I ended up saying more or less what you said below.....

Answer (score 1):

So to clarify the question: $A$ and $B$ both come to play the game and they each have their deterministic strategies--given the action of the host that is. $A$ picks Door 1 first and then after the host uncovers a door, picks the remaining door. Then $B$ picks Door 2 first and then after the host uncovers a door, picks the remaining door.

This means that (no matter whether or not the host favors opening Door 3) that $A$ wins and $B$ loses if the prize is behind Door #2, and $B$ wins and $A$ loses if the prize is behind Door #1, and both $A$ and $B$ win if the prize is behind Door #3.

This is another way of looking at it. Your analysis above didn't take into account that $A$ and $B$ with their strategies will be sometimes be forced into picking Door #3.

Let us now assume that both $A$ and $B$ each take their first picks as they have before, but now they both have secret knowledge that the host will always pick Door #3 whenever he can. Then both $A$ and $B$ know that the probability of being right changing their first picks **when the Host picks #3** is $\frac{1}{2}$ (not $\frac{2}{3}$), while the probability of being right switching **when the host picks another door besides #3** is actually 1. [make sure you see why]. So neither $A$ nor $B$ sees the prize as being more likely to be behind Door #1 instead of Door #2 or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it this way: in order to ensure that he always opens a non-prize door before offering the player a chance to switch, we ensure that *Monty* already knows which door the prize is behind.

So in your scenario, you have at least three people who have estimated the probability that the car is behind door $1.$ Their three answers fall into one of the following two cases:

- Player A's estimated probability is $\frac13,$ Player B's estimated probability is $\frac23,$ and Monty's estimated probability is $1.$
- Player A's estimated probability is $\frac13,$ Player B's estimated probability is $\frac23,$ and Monty's estimated probability is $0.$

The "contradiction" you've found is just an extension of the not-always-comfortable application of probability to situations where different people have different knowledge.
The probability that one estimates in those case is actually a conditional probability *given what one knows.*

- Player A knows that the rules prevented Monty from opening door $1,$ that Monty opened door $3,$ and that the car is not behind door $3.$
- Player B knows that the rules prevented Monty from opening door $2,$ that Monty opened door $3,$ and that the car is not behind door $3.$

What's "unique" about each player is that A knows something B does not know, and B knows something A does not know.

Monty, meanwhile, knows a lot more than either player:

- Monty knows that he opened door $3,$ that the car is behind door $x,$ and that he was prevented from opening either door $1$ or door $2$ by the players' choices (and in one case, also because the car was there).

If everyone knew what Monty knew, there would be none of this nonsense about probabilities of $\frac23$ or $\frac12$ that the car was behind a particular door;
the probability would be either $1$ or $0.$